# Issue with crc32c verification using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, crc32, gsutil

```
crc32c signature computed for local file (Rgw3kA==) doesn't match cloud-supplied digest (5A+KjA==). Local file (/home/blah/pgdata.tar) will be deleted.
```

I did a bit of diagnosing, and I noticed that it was always on the cloud-supplied digest of "5A+KjA==" but usually at a different point in the file with different local crc32c. This is using either:

```
gsutil -m rsync gs://bucket/ /
```

or

```
gsutil -m cp gs://bucket/pgdata.tar /
```

I seem to get this error almost all the time transferring a large 415GB tar database file. It always exits in error at a different part, and it doesn't resume. Is there any workarounds for this? If it is legitimate file corruption, I would expect it to fail at the same point in the file?

File seems fine as I've loaded this onto various instances and postgresql about a week ago.

I'm not sure of the verision of gsutils, but it is the natively installed one on GCE Ubuntu 14.04 image, following the GCE provided instructions for crcmod installation on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like you've already emailed gs-team@google.com - I'll follow up with you there and post the answer here once it has been diagnosed.

Comment: Thanks! Just running a new test now both before and after updates. I'll reply once it crashes with the old version, I've updated and the result with the new version.